# How to downgrade dotnet 6 preview to dotnet 5?

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

I have recently upgraded my dotnet version to dotnet 6 preview to tryout MAUI. How can I downgrade it again to dotnet 5?

Comment: .NET 5 will still be installed on your computer, assuming it was installed before. You should be able to just uninstall .NET 6. Obviously, you’ll need to update your `csproj` files to use a `<TargetFramework>` set to the `net5.0` moniker, and remove any .NET 6 specific libraries and code within your projects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**First**: uninstall dotnet6(.Net6) from your Visual Studio:

- open your Visual Studio
- go to "tools" -> "get tools and features" -> " Individual components"
  _ then uncheck "dotnet6(.Net6.0) Runtime" and press Modify and wait until the uninstallation complete

**Second**: go to "control panel" -> "uninstall a program" -> LF dotnet6(.Net6) package and uninstall it

**Third**: download dotnet5 from Microsoft web site : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0  then complete the process of installation

**Finally**: go to your cmd and type `dotnet --version` and you will find that it becomes: 5.0.405